# FindWindow Method error

Tags: powershell

I am trying get window of the Notepad using the following PowerShell script:

```
$pinvokes = @'
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr Connect(string className, string Notepad);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
'@

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -MemberDefinition $pinvokes -Name NativeMethods -Namespace MyUtils
$hwnd = [MyUtils.NativeMethods]::FindWindow($null, "Notepad")
```

But when I use `FindWindow()` I am getting the error below:

```
Method invocation failed because [MyUtils.NativeMethods] doesn't contain a method named 'FindWindow'.
At line:1 char:44
+ $hwnd = [MyUtils.NativeMethods]::FindWindow <<<< ($null, "Notepad")
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (FindWindow:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Comment: The code string exports 2 methods: `Connect()` and `SetForegroundWindow()`. Why are you surprised that you get an error when you try to invoke a method `FindWindow()` that wasn't exported in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified the "FindWindow" method in your $pinvokes definition.

Do the following after e.g. your last method in $pinvokes:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
```

Example:

```
$pinvokes = @'
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr Connect(string className, string Notepad);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
'@

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
# Using Passthru for example to show you how to return type directly    
$t = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $pinvokes -Name NativeMethods -Namespace MyUtils -PassThru
$hwnd = $t::FindWindow($null, "Notepad")
```